# onItemClick doesn't work with adapter (linear layout)

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have my custom adapter:

**allergy2_row.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="10dp"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">

        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/task_item_name"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            />

        <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/task_subitem_name"
        android:textSize="15dp"
            />



    </LinearLayout>

<CheckBox
android:id="@+id/task_item_done"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I need to create adapter so that it will be like this:
[image: adapter view]

I tried different layouts to make it - 2 linear layouts, relative layout, constraint layout. But they were not clickable. (When there was only one linear layout (with textview and checkbox), it worked fine.)
So, the click started not to work when I added another linear layout inside.

**Allergy2.java**

```
public class Allergy2 extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Realm realm;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_allergy2);
        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        RealmResults<Allergy2Task> tasks = realm.where(Allergy2Task.class).findAll();
        tasks = tasks.sort("timestamp");
        final Allergy2Adapter adapter = new Allergy2Adapter(this, tasks);

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.task_list);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                Context context = view.getContext();
                LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(context);
                layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);


                final Allergy2Task task = (Allergy2Task) adapterView.getAdapter().getItem(i);
                final EditText taskEditText = new EditText(Allergy2.this);
                final EditText task2EditText = new EditText(Allergy2.this);
                taskEditText.setSingleLine(true);
                taskEditText.setHint("Type ingredient");
                taskEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES);

                task2EditText.setSingleLine(true);
                task2EditText.setHint("Type synonyms(if any) separated by commas");
                task2EditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES);

                layout.addView(taskEditText);
                layout.addView(task2EditText);

                AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Allergy2.this)
                        .setTitle("Edit allergen")
                        .setView(layout)
                        .setPositiveButton("Save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                String ed_text = taskEditText.getText().toString().trim();
                                if (ed_text.isEmpty()) {
                                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                            "The field cannot be empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                                    toast.show();

                                } else {
                                    changeTaskName(task.getId(), String.valueOf(taskEditText.getText()));
                                }
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("Delete", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                deleteTask(task.getId());
                            }
                        })
                        .create();
                dialog.show();
            }
        });
}
```

That is adapter for this class:
**Allergy2Adapter.java**

```
public class Allergy2Adapter extends RealmBaseAdapter<Allergy2Task> implements ListAdapter {

    private Allergy2 activity;
    private Realm realm;

    private static class ViewHolder {
        TextView taskName;
        CheckBox isTaskDone;
    }

    Allergy2Adapter(Allergy2 activity, OrderedRealmCollection<Allergy2Task> data) {
        super(data);
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.allergy2_row, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.taskName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.task_item_name);
            viewHolder.isTaskDone = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.task_item_done);
            viewHolder.isTaskDone.setOnClickListener(listener);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        if (adapterData != null) {
            Allergy2Task task = adapterData.get(position);
            viewHolder.taskName.setText(task.getName());
            viewHolder.isTaskDone.setChecked(task.isDone());
            viewHolder.isTaskDone.setTag(position);
        }


        return convertView;
    }

    private View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int position = (Integer) view.getTag();
            if (adapterData != null) {
                Allergy2Task task = adapterData.get(position);
                activity.changeTaskDone(task.getId());
            }

        }

    };



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
   @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.allergy2_row, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.taskName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.task_item_name);
            viewHolder.isTaskDone = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.task_item_done);
            viewHolder.isTaskDone.setOnClickListener(listener);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        if (adapterData != null) {
            Allergy2Task task = adapterData.get(position);
            viewHolder.taskName.setText(task.getName());
            viewHolder.isTaskDone.setChecked(task.isDone());
            viewHolder.isTaskDone.setTag(position);
        }
             converView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

            if (adapterData != null) {
                Allergy2Task task = adapterData.get(position);
                activity.changeTaskDone(task.getId());
            } 
                }
            });

        return convertView;
    }
```